What could be the next technological revolution for a society that has FTL travel tech?
In a society with FTL travel tech that is relatively mature (like a Star Wars or Star Trek civilization), what could be the next technological breakthrough BESIDES teleportation (as I feel teleportation is a suicide machine)?

Footwear for cats. My guess. Alternatively, you could edit to make a question that's not asking for brainstorming and opinions.

Time travel. If you have FTL travel, you can travel in time on tricky FTL paths.

Teleportation, but to address your suicide machine concerns, these teleporters don't kill the original, they just create a perfect duplicate.

To be clear about the concerns... (a) breakthrough in what field? All fields? The most influential in all fields? That's impossible to answer. (b) Define "revolution." Expansion to the stars is a grand thing! But so would adding 30 productive years to human life and that's not as wondrous a story as FTL (medical breakthroughs never are, despite the revolution they cause). (c) Remember that you must ask a question in such a way as to anticipate objectively selecting a best answer. If you can't explain how you'll do that, the question is not ready to be asked.

FTL Communication tech
So, you have a ship that travel faster-than-light, but without real-time (or near-real-time two-way communication) - you will end up with a situation like the pre-Telegram days, where everything had to be done via Letter, carried on a Mail ship.
Societies can function like this (the did for several hundred years) but the advent of the Telegram and then two-way communication really is a massive game changer.

If there could be a single best and right answer, this would be it.

As far as we know, FTL travel would require breaking scientific paradigms in ways which are, well, impossible to predict from this side of the divide. Your society will develop in a number of fields and it is an arbitrary decision if FTL comes before or after self-organizing nanotech, before or after true artificial intelligence.
To get a workable multi-system society, you need the ability to transport people and goods over interstellar distances, in acceptable time and at acceptable prices. You introduced FTL, but that is just part of the story:

Many fictional FTL drives demand significant power. This may be collected by solar cells, generated by fusion or fission reactors, stored in capacitors or homopolar wheels, etc. Once you have the minimum, the power hunger of FTL might drive improvements. Say they start with fission reactors taking half the starship, then progress to fusion reactors taking only a quarter.
Many fictional FTL drives do not work from a planetary surface. So you need a launch system. If those still rely on hydrogen/oxygen or kerosene/oxygen rockets, there won't be much interstellar travel. You could have some reasonably clean technobabble-fusion drive, or antigravity, or drives ignoring the demands of Newtonian physics. Some of this may come before FTL, some after.
Many fictional FTL drives do not work from low orbit, or from the inner system. The drive to get from orbit to the place where FTL can be used may be the same as the drive to get into orbit, or a different technology with different tradeoffs (Isp, engine mass per pound of thrust, radiation danger zones, ...).

